# Should we always use the past if the person is no longer alive or when we refer to a past state

Tags: word-choice, tenses, past-tense, present-tense

When I want to point out that the person is still regarded as the best student till now, tho they have been gone or they are not a student anymore, what tense should I use, the present or the past? Please give a thought to the following: *Susan **is/was** still the best student I've ever taught*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we shouldn't always do so. We say *Shakespeare is...* when discussing his works rather than his personal life.

Certainly if Susan is still alive, but no longer a student, the present tense would be appropriate. If she has died, I think the past tense would be used, as it's about her as a person.

Comment: Got it. What if it came to a prophet? Should we say *the prophet **encourages** kindness*, or *the prophet **encouraged** kindness*?

Comment: With reference to the prophet's writings or reported sayings, I think you can use the present tense.

Comment: Got it. One more situation in my mind, Bunting. Someone asks someone else: *In your opinion, who is the best in your family?* The person answers: *my mother*. If the person would like to include the verb, what would it be, *is* or *was*, if the mother has passed away?

Comment: The same thing applies here as I told you about 'Susan' - when describing the personal qualities of someone who is deceased, we use the past tense. (By the way, it's not usual to address a woman by her surname!)

Comment: sorry, Kate. So sorry for that. Hope u'll accept my apology. I am an Indian who lives in Indonesia. I am in the process to understand American and British cultures better. It's quite hard since the cultures are completely different to that in my country. Thanks a lot for the answer, Kate :)